# SharePoint 2013 parse default.aspx Pages

Tags: 2013, search

In a SharePoint 2013 Intranet Search, i am unable to find Pages named "default.aspx" via Search.
The default.aspx Pages are set as Publishing Home Pages for webs, the search did find and index the web, not the page.

- http://root/site/web01/pages/default.aspx [Title01]
- http://root/site/web02/pages/default.aspx [Title02]
- http://root/site/web03/pages/default.aspx [Title03]

=> Searching for "Title03" works!

A reorganization into a single Site - Folder did break everything.

- http://root/site/pages/folder01/default.aspx [Title01]
- http://root/site/pages/folder02/default.aspx [Title02]
- http://root/site/pages/folder03/default.aspx [Title03]

**=> Searching for "Title03" doesn`t work**

pages show up in the crawl log as successfully crawled properties are not coming.

I tried all Result Sources, tried renaming the Files, tried setting the homepage of site to a differently named page, i tried crawl rules, index resetting, full crawling, ... any ideas left?